# Hover effect in <ul> <li> list with Headings

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` `<li>` list where in **HELP, MISC and POLICIES** are the headings with no `<a>` tag. 
other `<li>` elements have `hover` effect as `font-size:16px` (normal size is 14px).

how can i remove `hover` of headings??

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SPCcJ/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
.footer_ul li.bold1:hover {
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

to remove the hover of headings

**[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/SPCcJ/5/)**

or alternate you can use `.footer_ul li a:hover` instate of `.footer_ul li:hover`

```
.footer_ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPCcJ/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
I checked you fiddle it was good.

The only change you need to make is you have to add :hover class for a tag and not li tag

`

.footer_ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:16px;
}


`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not()` selector. A single change is required like so.

```
.footer_ul li:hover:not(.bold1) {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPCcJ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css after ".footer_ul li:hover"

```
.footer_ul li:hover:first-child {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
}
```